# How to style the value of a placeholder like if I want to give a margin at left of that value, what to write in css?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="user_name floatleft fix">
        <input placeholder="User name" type="text"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to give some margin at left of "User name" in input. Please help.

Comment: did you want to style _only_ the placeholder? @dowomenfart's answer affects anything the user enters into the <input>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give padding to the `input` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yyz8ce09/)

```
input{
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

If you want to be more specific and not effect all inputs in your HTML. You can do this:

```
.user_name > input {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```